# sed - Reverse DNS Extraction

Tags: dns, sed, extract

I'm trying to extract DNS PTR records out of a Microsoft zone, so that I can stage them to import them into a BIND zone.  I have all the reverses, and they are in the following format:

```
1.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa.  1200    IN  PTR my.long.domain.net.
22.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa. 1200    IN  PTR your.long.domain.net.
33.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa. 1200    IN  PTR our.long.domain.net.
```

What I am trying to do is extract the initial octet (in this case, the 1, 22, and 33 out of each line - at the beginning), but then I want to remove everything else, all the way to the "PTR" item.  I then want to keep the "PTR" item as well as the actual reverse (for ex. my.long.domain.net.  So, my guess would to use sed and the output that I want to end up with (using the example from above), would be:

```
1       PTR     my.long.domain.net.
22      PTR     your.long.domain.net.
33      PTR     our.long.domain.net.
```

Is this something sed can do and how would I go about doing that?  I'm by far any sed expert.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\..*(\sPTR)/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
 sed 's/\s\{1,\}/ /g;s/\([^.]*\).*PTR /\1       PTR     /;s/^\(........\) */\1/'
```

Some of that is just to get the spacing you show in your desired output, if all you wanted were single spaced fields this would do:

```
sed 's/\s\{1,\}/ /g;s/\([^.]*\).*PTR /\1 PTR /'
```

Comment: William - I think I found an issue with my example that will help, since your solution didn't work (which I think is my bad).  The ex. I showed you has spaces, whereas my original file that has the zones in it, where there are space, those actually look like tabs.  Is there a way for you to revise your solution to possibly look for tabs, rather than spaces?

Comment: Edited to replace any whitespace with single spaces. If your version of sed doesn't like `\s` for a whitespace character try \t for tabs or the POSIX class [[:space:]] instead, otherwise you may need to insert a literal tab character in a class `[^i]` where ^i is control-i (try typing control-v, control-i to insert it, that often works).